# android custom title bar with overlapping logo

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to have this kind of custom title bar in my Android application:

[image]

- A custom title bar
- With two standard buttons, one left aligned (A) and one right aligned (C)
- A clickable logo in the middle (B)
- With this logo exceeding the title bar and overlapping the content

When clicking on (A) or (C), it would start an activity.
When clicking on (B) it would present a little menu, eventually starting other activities.

Do you know how this can be achieved in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Am using `Relative layout` and  `Framelayout`.

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button2" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/parent_linear" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book" />
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do this directly in the ActionBar but you could use a RelativeLayout and bind the bar to the top.

Something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <-- All the stuff to design the bar -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Plus you could remove the standard title bar and use a no-title theme.

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

PS:
nice drawing.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know about it! :D